If salvation is by faith, and faith comes by hearing the word of Christ, can we be saved without having heard of Jesus?
The Bible says

It is by grace that you are saved, by the means of faith. And it does not come from you, it is the gift of God’. (Eph 2:8).


So faith comes from what we hear, and what we hear comes from the word of Christ.’ (Rom 10:17).

According to the passages of the Bible quoted (Ephesians 2:8 and Romans 10:17), faith and grace are necessary for salvation. However, these passages also emphasize the importance of hearing the word of Christ. In this context, is it possible to be saved without having heard of Jesus?
Can we be saved without having heard of Jesus?

Welcome to the group. Some theologians like Karl Rahner speak of "anonymous Christians" who have responded to God's grace without hearing of Jesus.

By the way to avoid having your question closed as "opinion based" you might want to phrase it differently such as "what are the arguments in favor of the proposition that we can be saved with hearing of Jesus?" I realize this may feel like nit-picking but that's how the culture of our group has developed.

There is one name given among men, under heaven, whereby we must be saved. Acts 4:12.

@NigelJ, the 'name'; not Joshua, Joses, Jesus ... but the person. That feasible?

@RobCallicotte The name 'Jesus' (given by angelic communication) identitifies and locates a Person. This is specific. Only that Person, as identified and located, can save me. Otherwise, I perish.

Jeremie, your rephrased question needed to be edited into the body of your question, not just given as a comment. So, I have done that for you and hope that will help your question stay open, though you still need to identify a particular group you wish to get answers from. Blessings.

@NigelJ, that person represents a name, which is his Father's Name. And John 17 makes this abundantly clear. Anything else is willing isolation from reality. God's name is exalted in the Earth, though he will someday consume it in fire because of the rejection of this Name; not because people aren't theologians or haven't seen a Bible or cannot see history about a man named Jesus, who (for all intents and purposes) represented this Name while on Earth. Finding Jesus, yes. But, the Name is what matters. "Father, glorify Your name.” (from John 12)

@NigelJ God the Father sent Jesus to saved mankind, but clearly, the one who can save mankind is God the Father. And we can see this clearly in Magnificat. Mary said, "my spirit rejoices in God my Savior". Mary was already saved even before Jesus finished His redemptive mission. So, the Savior that Mary was referring to, is not Jesus but God the Father. Likewise, those who never heard of the gospel can be saved, in the mysterious ways unknown to Church and ofcourse to Bible Alone Believers like you. Lumen Gentium par.16 explain this teachings clearly. -Wisdom9:18 is the salvation of OT people.

There is a sense in saying that the bible is silent about it. I do not think the bible teaches whether those who did not hear the gospel will be saved. However, there are hints in that direction. I would think the bible is silent about it. Here are my reasons:

“For as many as have sinned without law shall also perish without law: and as many as have sinned in the law shall be judged by the law;” (Rom 2:12, KJV)

There are two caterogies of mankind elucidated in the scripture above.

Those who received the Law of Moses from the mount - The Physical Jews
Those who did not officially recieve the two tablets of stones - The Gentiles.

The Jews will be judged based on the two tablets they have but the Gentiles who did not officially have the two tablets of stone (The Gentiles) will be judge based on the law in their conscience.
What did Paul teach about these two people?
“As it is written, There is none righteous, no, not one: There is none that understandeth, there is none that seeketh after God. They are all gone out of the way, they are together become unprofitable; there is none that doeth good, no, not one.” (Rom 3:10-12, KJV)
Paul's conclusion is this: There is none righteous, no not one
It means that no Jew, by obedience to the law became righteous! In fact, it is not possible. It also means that no gentile, by obedience to the things contained in the law via their conscience became righteous. In fact, again, it is not possible.
Hence, no one in history got saved under any of those two methods; no one will be saved by those methods. This portends that Paul's arguement in Rom.2:12-15 are hypotheitical because he concluded that there is none righteous, no not one. In fact he stretched it further saying that There is none that understandeth, there is none that seeketh after God.
He concluded both Jews and Gentiles under sin inspite of their dedication. As far as Paul is concerned, they are not seeking God. Both Jews and Gentiles trying to obey the law which ever way do not understand. They do not understand that their methods are not the way to salvation. They are not really seeking God.
Were there poeple who got saved before Christ? Yes.
Abel was saved. Matt.23:25; Heb.11:4. He was not justified by his action of the sacrifice he gave, He was justified by faith long before this. Jesus called him Righteous Abel.
Enoch was saved! Heb.11:5; Jude 1:14

And Enoch also, the seventh from Adam, prophesied of these, saying, Behold, the Lord cometh with ten thousands of his saints. Jud.1:14

He saw the judgement to come. He 'saw' the coming Jesus and he believed it. In fact, he became a prophet in his generation in the dispensation of conscience. This was before he became translated. so, you see that Enoch was already justified before he was translated. Without being justified first, he would not be a prophet of God.
So, having been justified by faith, he continued to walk with God by this faith wherewith he was justified with. He didn't change the method. He simply continued to walk by faith.
There are many more that time and space would not allow me to write about here.
Did Abel know there would be a coming Messiah? Yes. Did he know the Messaih would be called Jesus? We are not told. Did Enoch know about a coming deliverer? Yes. Jud.1:14. Did he know that his name would be Jesus? We are not told.
What am I driving at? The common denominators between Abel and Enoch and many others are:

They see that the world and the earth is not in the right state.
They knew there would be a Messiah.
They knew that the Messiah will execute judgement.
They looked for they (e.g. Abrham) looked for a city which hath foundations, whose builder and maker is God.
They believed in the above truths and lived their life accordingly in response to them.

If people will be saved without hearing about Jesus, The above listed points must be known via God revealing these truths to them.
The writer of the book to the Hebrews says it his own way:

“But without faith it is impossible to please him: for he that cometh to God must believe that he is, and that he is a rewarder of them that diligently seek him.” (Heb 11:6, KJV)

He says "...without faith...it is impossible...to please him"
Faith is the only means. That is the only way God gives good report. Heb.11:2. That is the only way God is pleased. Heb.11:6
What if they did not hear about Jesus. They have to believe, at least, the points listed above common to all who were saved without hearing the name Jesus.
I think it is only in this sense would some be saved without hearing about Jesus.

Well written, is this an evangelical perspective?

Intelligent and balanced response. Up-voted +1.

@Wyrsa As an evangelical, I would say so.  I would also add that if someone is living out faith in OP's 5 points in this day and age the Lord will respond to that faith by sending the fullness of the gospel through some preacher or prophet.  example: Acts 10, Acts 18:24-26.

@MikeBorden It is just interesting to see it. I believe in Apokatatasis so yeah, God will respond to you based on how to acted and behaved, and your relationship with him and the unique circumstances of your life...

I answer as one of those in the Reformed Protestant category. Three considerations strike me as worth mentioning.

Huge numbers of people have heard of Jesus, but they remain unsaved.

People who are totally deaf cannot either hear Jesus, or hear preaching about him, i.e. the word of Christ.

Jesus fulfilled the prophecy to open the ears of the deaf, doing that literally, and spiritually.


Point number 1 needs to be mentioned, to disabuse anyone of the idea that hearing the word of Christ (i.e. the gospel, or good news of Christ) will, in itself, bring salvation to people. As the question mentions, salvation is by faith. Only a hearing of the word of Christ that is accompanied with faith will save anyone. Several of the prophets of old were told by God, before their preaching ministry started, that they would not be listened to, yet they still had to give the warning message. Jesus said that a prophet is not honoured in his home town. This means that, although audible proclamation about Jesus is required of his witnesses (John 1:7 & Acts 1:8), that cannot be viewed like some kind of magic wand.
Point number 2 is not a facetious point because there is a need to consider other ways for totally deaf people to learn the good new of the gospel of Christ. This is where the written word is vital. Likewise with totally blind people – they cannot see the written word of God. And some people are both blind and deaf.  Yet, “Thus saith the Lord… when I called, was there none to answer? Is my arm shortened at all, that it cannot redeem? Or have I no power to deliver?” (Isaiah 50:2 A.V.)
This is immensely encouraging, “For the Lord knows those who are his” (2 Timothy 2:18-19). It is entirely God who identifies and brings to spiritual birth those who will be saved, and Jesus was assured by the Father that not one person who had been appointed to salvation would be lost to him (John 6:39).
Point number 3 comes in here, as he who created the ear hears himself, even silent cries unto him. When God incarnate walked on Earth, he unstopped the ears of many deaf people, as well as made the spiritually deaf to hear him. He spoke of those who hear but who do not understand, and looking, but do not see. The spiritually dead can neither hear nor see. But Jesus brings new life – salvation – for faith is a gift from God, “so that no man can boast” (Ephesians 2:9).
Conclusion: All who are, and who yet will, be saved, shall assuredly hear of Jesus, with understanding that is of faith. Not one shall be lost. The grace of God ensures that they all hear of Christ so as to believe in him.

I agree that people who have not heard the Gospel most likely will be lost, and besides the arguments presented here, I want to add personal conviction. Let's review the warning God gave Cain before he killed his brother:
"If you do well, will you not be accepted? And if you do not do well, sin is crouching at the door. Its desire is contrary to you, but you must rule over it" Genesis 4:7
Notice that early on in human history we were made aware that we are in charge of ourselves, we are responsible for our actions and emotions, that was the warning God gave Cain which he disdained, and so it is with anyone today.
So even if we do not hear the Gospel, we know in ourselves when we have gone against the moral values God instilled in us when we were born.


God, who at sundry times and in divers manners spake in time past unto the fathers by the prophets, Hath in these last days spoken unto us by his Son, whom he hath appointed heir of all things, by whom also he made the worlds; Heb 1:1-2

The examples in Hebrews 11 follow this pattern.

And these all, having obtained a good report through faith, received not the promise: God having provided some better thing for us, that they without us should not be made perfect. Heb 11:39-40

And what was that?

Looking unto Jesus the author and finisher of our faith; who for the joy that was set before him endured the cross, despising the shame, and is set down at the right hand of the throne of God. Heb 12:2

So, to answer the OP, there was faith about Christ/God, not yet fulfilled, but now that Christ has come, salvation requires faith in Christ.

Eastern Orthodoxy: "Yes*"

So here the 4 issues with this answer.

"Will render men slothful, and discourage them from keeping the commandments of God. It will encourage them to depart from the narrow way, leading them by deception into ways that are wide and easy."

"...such a doctrine completely contradicts the words of our Great God and Savior. For in the Holy Gospel he himself teaches that the impious will be sent away into eternal punishment, but the righteous will receive life eternal."

"...if both the torments of hell and the pleasures of paradise should cease, what was the point of the Incarnation of our Lord Jesus Christ? What was the purpose of his crucifixion, his death, burial, and resurrection?

"And what of all those who fought the good fight and suffered martyrdom for the sake of Christ? What benefit will their sufferings have been to them, if in the “final restoration” they will receive the same reward as sinners and demons?"



Against Origen PG86.975 BD


Responses to these 4 issues.

The criticism implies that fear of damnation is a better motivation for repentance than love and hope. When we look at faith, what kind of faith is it when you are threatened with eternal suffering? Does faith based on fear save?


“striking sensitive hearts with horror, paralyzing filial love and the childlike trust in the Heavenly Father, this idea makes Christianity resemble Islam, replacing love with fear. Salvific fear, too, must also have its measure, and not become an attempt to terrorize” (Sergius Bulgakov, The Bride of the Lamb, p. 484).

Our Loving God is not trying to strike us with absolute terror, He loves us. It is the difference between being forced to work for someone, you do it begrudgingly... and actually wanting to serve someone, you do it with intent eagerness and respect.

This is an error, a misunderstanding of the word "Aionion" (αἰών).


The words used by Christ are "“will depart into eternal [aionion] punishment, but the righteous into eternal [aionion] life” (Matt 25:46)."


As for the NT, the points that could be interpreted as teaching an eternal damnation, and therefore contradicting the theory of apokatastasis, consist in the few passages that mention a πῦρ αἰώνιον, a κόλασις αἰώνιος, a fire “that cannot be quenched” and a worm that “does not die” (see, for instance, Matt 18:8–9; 25:41). Now, such expressions, rather than signifying an infinite duration, indicate that the fire, punishment, and worm at stake are not those of human everyday experience in this world, in which fire can be extinguished and worms die, but others, of the other world or αἰών. The adjective αἰώνιος in the Bible never means “eternal” unless it refers to God, who lends it the very notion of absolute eternity. In reference to life and death, it means “belonging to the future world.” It is remarkable that in the Bible only life in the other world is called ἀΐδιος, that is, “absolutely eternal”; this adjective in the Bible never refers to punishment, death, or fire in the other world. These are only called αἰώνια. (Ilaria Ramelli, The Christian Doctrine of Apokatastasis, p 26)

Sixth century speakers somehow understood αἰών to mean "eternal, unending, interminable, everlasting" ...

“In Scriptures, αἰών is sometimes found in the sense of something that knows no end; at times it designates something that has no end in the present world, but will have in the future one; sometimes it means a certain stretch of time; or again the duration of the life of a single person is called αἰών” (Origen, Comm. in Rom. 6,5)

So this objection is just a misunderstanding. This was further cemented by the translation into latin by St. Jerome... "αἰών" became "æternum" ... yikes.

This objection makes the saving work of Christ "lesser".

Is Christ's sacrifice less significant if He saves all people, instead of some?

For this is good and acceptable in the sight of God our Savior, who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth. (1 Timothy 2:3-4)

Keep in mind, human freedom is maintained here. God is not forcing us with almighty power. (Neither Origen nor Nyssen taught this) That thought would make the incarnation mere charade. (Not even Tom Talbott teaches that)

This objection is based on the idea that "the reward" is equally given to everyone. How awful would it be if serial criminals and saints both received the same reward... Which is a great point for mortals on earth. But what of the workers in the vineyard?


“For the kingdom of heaven is like a householder who went out early in the morning to hire laborers for his vineyard. After agreeing with the laborers for a denarius a day, he sent them into his vineyard. And going out about the third hour he saw others standing idle in the market place; and to them he said, ‘You go into the vineyard too, and whatever is right I will give you.’ So they went. Going out again about the sixth hour and the ninth hour, he did the same. And about the eleventh hour he went out and found others standing; and he said to them, ‘Why do you stand here idle all day?’ They said to him, ‘Because no one has hired us.’ He said to them, ‘You go into the vineyard too.’ And when evening came, the owner of the vineyard said to his steward, ‘Call the laborers and pay them their wages, beginning with the last, up to the first.’ And when those hired about the eleventh hour came, each of them received a denarius. Now when the first came, they thought they would receive more; but each of them also received a denarius. And on receiving it they grumbled at the householder, saying, ‘These last worked only one hour, and you have made them equal to us who have borne the burden of the day and the scorching heat.’ But he replied to one of them, ‘Friend, I am doing you no wrong; did you not agree with me for a denarius? Take what belongs to you, and go; I choose to give to this last as I give to you. Am I not allowed to do what I choose with what belongs to me? Or do you begrudge my generosity?’ So the last will be first, and the first last.” (Matthew 20:1-16)

It seems God's love and generosity is somewhat above our understanding. If satan can eventually be restored by our Great and Loving God. So can all of us.

There are Eastern Orthodox who disagree. I acknowledge that.
I choose to believe and trust that God is truly Love. That His plan will save us all. And I freely admit, I'm not sure how He will do it, only that He will.

This question was addressed directly in an encyclical of Pope Pius IX, published on August 10, 1863, Quanto Conficiamur Moerore;
"It is known to Us and to You that those who are in an invincible ignorance of Our most holy religion, but who carefully observe the natural law and its precepts, engraved by God in the hearts of all; who are willing to obey God and who lead an honest and upright life, can, with the help of divine light and grace, attain eternal life. For God sees perfectly, scrutinizes, knows the spirits, souls, thoughts, habits of all, and in his supreme goodness, in his infinite clemency, he does not allow anyone to suffer eternal punishments without being guilty of some voluntary sin. Likewise the Catholic dogma is well known, according to which outside the Catholic Church no one can be saved, and those who are rebellious against the authority and decisions of the Church, those who are obstinately separated from the unity of the Church herself, and from the Roman Pontiff, the Successor of Peter, to whom the custody of the vineyard has been entrusted by the Saviour, cannot obtain eternal salvation."
I should note that Invincible Ignorance of this form is most unlikely through the world today. Except for rare situations most peoples have heard of Jesus and some part of His ministry, even in negative format, and so come to Accept or Reject the working of the Holy Ghost His name Calls forth.
Also, I direct attention to this older Statement of Traditional Catholic doctrine, as the heretical 'Whore of Babylon' Vatican II Modernists version has not stood the test of time and acceptance, and since Vatican II holds a number of Heresies so by the Will of God should not be so Verified as other Counsels have been; Trent and Vatican I as examples.

As one with less then 50 (50!) points I can only comment here; in RaySolva Question point " Seems like John the Baptist is the greatest example .." It is widely considered that in the Greeting by Holy Mother Mary on visitation to her cousin Elisabeth, that unborn John the Baptist was cleansed of Original Sin. In Ryan Pierce Williams's question 'Christian Love' is Whishing the Good of the Other, and clearly since include strangers and enemies is different the plain 'love'.

Sadly, it seems that - by my count - 3 Answers of (-1) score, out of 12 Answers to 12 Questions here has somehow blocked my ability to Answer questions. So, the moderators anti-Catholics, and GramerNazis will not have me to kick-around for a while.

This is a matter of opinion but the NT does provide some support for the idea. The term "anonymous Christian" was coined by theologian Karl Rahner in support of the proposition that people can be saved without knowing Jesus. Biblical verses that support the idea include:
Romans 2

14 For when the Gentiles who do not have the law by nature observe the
prescriptions of the law, they are a law for themselves even though
they do not have the law. 15 They show that the demands of the law are
written in their hearts as their own conscience also bears witness, and their conflicting thoughts will accuse or perhaps excuse them 16 on the day when, according to my gospel, God through Christ Jesus judges the secret thoughts of all.

Here the apostle holds open the possibility that non-Christians who follow their conscience will be saved in the end.
Matthew 25

31 “When the Son of Man comes in his glory, and all the angels with
him, he will sit upon his glorious throne, 32 and all the nations will
be assembled before him. And he will separate them one from another,
as a shepherd separates the sheep from the goats. 33 He will place the
sheep on his right and the goats on his left. 34 Then the king will
say to those on his right, ‘Come, you who are blessed by my Father.
Inherit the kingdom prepared for you from the foundation of the world.
35 For I was hungry and you gave me food, I was thirsty and you gave
me drink, a stranger and you welcomed me, 36 naked and you clothed me,
ill and you cared for me, in prison and you visited me.’ 37 Then the
righteous will answer him and say, ‘Lord, when did we see you
hungry and feed you, or thirsty and give you drink? 38 When did we see
you a stranger and welcome you, or naked and clothe you? 39 When did
we see you ill or in prison, and visit you?’ 40 And the king will say
to them in reply, ‘Amen, I say to you, whatever you did for one of
these least brothers of mine, you did for me.’

This implies a kind of social gospel, in which people are saved through services rather than faith in Jesus per se. Also the Old Testament we can find many verses expressing that a person was saved by God directly long before the intervention of Christ.
Conclusion: there is biblical support for the idea that people can be saved by following their conscience and service others. However this doctrine is controversial as it runs counter to texts such as Acts 4:12 - “There is salvation in no one else, for there is no other name under heaven given among mortals by which we must be saved.”

Which transalation is this? The KJV (and some others) have verses 13 through 15 as a parenthetical remark, leaving the actual message "For as many as have sinned without law will also perish without law, and as many as have sinned in the law will be judged by the law (…) in the day when God will judge the secrets of men by Jesus Christ, according to my gospel.". That gives it a completely different meaning.
¶ "social gospel, in which people are saved through services rather than faith" — I'd interpret it more as showing people being refused salvation because of their lack of service.

Yes - Rom 2:14-16 is the best answer to this question.  Further, how are all the OT people saved that were no-Jews such as Pharoah (Gen 12:17-20), Abimelech (Gen 20:3-6, Gen 26:8-11), Achish (1 Sam 29:6, 7), Necho (2 Chron 35:20-22), Ninevites, (Jonah 3:4-10), etc.

@RayButterworth - I used the NABRE.  KJV is in the minority here. It would be interesting to know why other (usually older) translations place 13-15 in parentheses. I wonder if  this is a decision of the editors or if it is  based on manuscript traditions.

@Dottard asks "how are all the OT people saved that were no-Jews such as Pharoah (Gen 12:17-20), Abimelech (Gen 20:3-6, Gen 26:8-11), …, etc."
— They weren't (but perhaps will be). See my recent answer to  By the phrase "οὔτε ἐν τῷ μέλλοντι", was Jesus saying that there are sins that could be forgiven after death?.

Being a law for themselves cannot be a good thing.  This is the fruit of the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil:  I don't need God to tell me, I can discern it for myself.  Hence the internal accusing and excusing.

@MikeBorden... yes, it can be a good thing. Most commentators understand the phrase to mean something like Gill says: "which they have by nature and use, and which natural reason dictates to them." The  phrase does not mean the same as our English expression "a law unto himself," which indeed means the willful disregard of divine and civil law.

Faith is the means / instrument through which salvation comes to us, but it does not in and of itself bestow salvation. As James says, even the demons believe - and shudder.
What then is the function of faith such that it can lead to salvation? And why do some who believe yet fear and perish?
Its function is to guide our actions, how we choose to live our lives, what we devote ourselves to. We are judged and rewarded accordingly; for good or for ill. This is why Jesus says you must lose your life to save it. Jesus paved the way, but we must still walk it.
Of course, as Paul notes in Romans 2, even those who did not receive the Law yet demonstrate that it is written on their hearts; and their conscience will both defend and accuse them before God.
We were made in God’s image, and God is love. The Law is also love. The way that scripture says that we may recognize a true Christian is through their love which shows them to be children of God.
Love, then, is the way to salvation- and this is available to all regardless of when or where they were born, and whether or not they have ever had access to the Gospel. We are all capable of it for we were made to love and to be loved.
So then, even independent of faith, people can choose to love and do the right thing. And those who pursue what is good and righteous will not be denied their reward of salvation.
Faith gives us the advantage of knowing what God wants from us, and the disadvantage- the curse - that we are increasingly accountable for our actions in proportion to our faith and understanding. But love makes us known by God.
Paul taught that these three remain: faith, hope, and love; and that the greatest of these is love. Yet if people can live a life of love and still be damned for lack of faith, then Paul’s wisdom falls flat. Faith would be superior if that is what God judges us by, if that is what determines whether we are to be saved or damned.
Furthermore, faith is said to be a gift from God. If we are judged by our faith, then this reduces the judgement to favoritism. Whoever God blessed with the gift of faith would be saved while whoever was not so blessed would be damned. Yet that is not just; in fact it is sin. Fortunately for everyone, there is no favoritism with God - and his judgment true.
So then, faith guides us - but love saves us. And it is love - not faith - that we are judged by. Thus even the non-believer, if they choose to pursue what is right and good and to love, will also be saved.
And the believer who knows and understands all matters of faith, yet chooses to live selfishly and hatefully, then they should fear the coming day of wrath like the demons do.

So we don't need Jesus!  All you need is love; doo, doo, doo, doo, doo!  Lennon was right!  Oh, but love is a fruit of the indwelling Spirit which doesn't come apart from Jesus' sending (16:7).  Christian brotherly love is the evidence of salvation not the means.  The love of God, demonstrated in Christ, is the means.  Also, it is arguably the entire mechanism of "salvation by grace through faith" that is the gift of God and not just faith itself.

" the believer who knows and understands all matters of faith, yet chooses to live selfishly and hatefully" is demonstrating that he is not a believer...just a profess-er.

@MikeBorden As I noted, Jesus paved the path - it is through him that any salvation has been made possible. Jesus atoned for all, once and for all. That holds true whether someone believes in him or not.

And no - love is not a manifestation of salvation. Everyone is capable of love and shows love. It is those who persist in love that will be saved.

Yes, unbelievers love (Luke 6:32).  There is a different love.  The fruit of the Spirit is ...?

It’s not a different love. It’s agape in both cases.

It is different.  Luke 6:32 is common human agape with or apart from belief and Luke 6:35 is agape that is God's agape poured out through a believer.  The first is love based upon a return and the second is love irregardless of return.

@MikeBorden scripture doesn’t differentiate between different agape. Love is love. Christians are called to love with a greater scope (even one’s enemies) and depth (with Christ exemplifying the greatest love in sacrificing himself for us) - but it is the same love that anyone and everyone is fully capable of. Your insistence that they are different is not rooted in scripture but in your false preconceptions

Christians are empowered to love with a greater scope and depth.  "It is God working in you to will and to do of His good pleasure".  If I can love my enemy, it is not me producing that love...it is a fruit of the indwelling Spirit..lest I pat myself on the back.

Those who are not Christian have also called for us to love everyone and they have also sacrificed themselves - even their lives - for their loved ones. There is nothing different about the love non-Christians show vs what a Christian shows. You have zero scriptural basis for insisting Christian love is distinct from that of a non-Christian - and it is shown to be blatantly false if you just look around you. You are simply motivated to deny any responsibility for your faith - the idea that you must do things. James 2 calls you a fool

"they have also sacrificed themselves - even their lives - for their loved ones".  Absolutely!  This is baseline humanity as elucidated in Luke 6:32.  Those who belong to Christ are called, and empowered, to do so for their enemies...to do what is beyond our innate, merely human ability and desire.  Not that we have no responsibility to live out our faith but that we cannot live it out in our own strength without Divine intervention.  If Christ is merely an example and not an indwelling, empowering Spirit lusting within us against the flesh it is vanity and vexation of spirit.

"And this commandment have we from him, That he who loveth God love his brother also." is not necessarily true in the inverse.  Just because one loves his brother does not necessarily mean that he loves God.  It is a fruit of the Spirit so that we will not boast.

@MikeBorden Even non-Christians have shown love and compassion for their enemies. Indeed, there is no loving action which you can find that is only done by true Christians. Your insistence that there is some supernatural love that we only gain access to with the baptism of the Holy Spirit has no foundation either in scripture or in the experience of our daily lives.

I will point you in the direction of Romans 5:5 but I fear that would do a little good.  The conclusion you voiced in your answer, "Thus even the non-believer, if they choose to pursue what is right and good and to love, will also be saved." is certainly at odds with biblical Christianity.  Perhaps a prayerful reading of 1 Peter chapter 4 might help?

Clearly, Paul told the Philippian jailer to believe on the Lord Jesus Christ in order to be saved rather than telling him to muster up the appropriate kind and amount of love for his fellow man in order to be saved. As I've pointed out in this conversation already love is a fruit of the Spirit.  It makes little sense for the spirit to indwell someone who believes and produce a fruit in them that they were already capable of producing apart from belief.

@MikeBorden you have all kinds of ridiculous errors going on. Not only do you insist upon a special kind of love reserved only for the believer despite no evidence for it - but you also appear to think that receiving the HS = possession. A Christian doesn’t lose their freewill; if they do good it’s because they decide to do so, and if they do bad it’s because they chose to do so. You have a fundamentally erroneous understanding of the HS.

You are asserting that the fruit of the Spirit can be manifested by an unbeliever,who, by definition, does not have the Spirit. If you'd like to go over into chat I will follow. Otherwise I think we should be done here.

@MikeBorden love is one fruit of the Spirit - and you have already conceded that non-believers love. Peace is another - do you think there is only ever war between non-Christians and never peace? Joy is another- do you think non-Christians never experience joy? etc.

I'm afraid that @ Ryan Pierce Williams post has surreptitiuosly made Jesus Christ and Salvation of no effect. This is a denial of the core and pillar of the christian faith. According to his comment, the grand summary is that Christ died in vain.

@BOAVINTURAFERREIRA I have said nothing of the sort - all salvation is through Christ. That applies for both believers and non-believers.

Peace is given not as the world gives.  There is either a distinction or the Holy Spirit produces a fruit that the flesh can produce just fine all on its own. Your argument is not with me sir.

@MikeBorden Once more you insist on creating distinctions that aren’t found in scripture. Love is love, peace is peace, and joy is joy. There aren’t special Holy Spirit varieties of these concepts. Rather, if what was offered by the HS was so radically different and foreign to mankind, then we wouldn’t have words to describe them - or else scripture would make a point of defining what God means by them to distinguish them from everyday use. But that’s not what we find. Instead God intentionally communicates with us using our own languages, with everyday words. ie, you are adding to scripture

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
